# How to solve $\arccos (\sin \frac{\pi}{8})$?

Tags: trigonometry

I can't solve it, despite applying the method of solving using a right triangle as in $\cos (\arctan \frac {3}{ 5})$. The question asks for calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's good for beginners to always think of arc functions as angles.  I'd set

$$\arccos \sin \frac{\pi}{8} = \theta,$$  so that

$$\sin \frac{\pi}{8} = \cos \theta.$$

Now you can just realize that the "co" in "cosine" is short for "complementary", so $\theta$ is the complementary angle to $\frac{\pi}{8}$, that is $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{8}.$

Comment: Actually, this is the best answer here.  I'm out of votes for the next six hours, but I'll favorite the question so I can come back to upvote it!

Answer (score 4):

For any $\theta\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ we have

$$ \arccos\sin\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\sin\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta.$$

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$\sin\alpha=\cos(\frac12\pi-\alpha)$